# Specifying Location of Code Coverage Data FIle

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I'm trying to integrate code coverage with Travis CI for a python repository.

In the project root, my `.coveragerc` looks like:

```
[run]
data_file = tests/coverage/.coverage
omit = data-structures/lib/*

[html]
directory = tests/coverage/html_report/

[xml]
output = tests/coverage/coverage.xml
```

All the attributes are reflected correctly **except** `data_file`. I see a `reports` file created under `tests/`.

I have also tried `data_file = tests/coverage/`, but the `reports` file is still created under `tests/`.

How do I create `.coverage` inside `tests/coverage/`?

Comment: Hmm, that seems very strange.  Are you sure you are using the .coveragerc file you think you are?  You can add COVERAGE_DEBUG=config,sys to your environment to get some information dumped about the configuration being used.

Comment: @NedBatchelder its working fine right now and the behavior is also as expected. But there was a `reports` file at some point earlier.