# Coverage - PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, macos, unit-testing, code-coverage, coverage.py

I using *pytest* and *coverage* modules for test cases and code coverage.

From the project root, I'm able to execute `pytest -v` but not `pytest -v --cov=./` (stack trace below)

I set `PYTHONPATH` to the project's root directory.

Directory permissions and ownership are `drwxr-xr-x` and `saurabh  staff`. Terminal application has full disk access.

My `.coveragerc` (located at project root) looks like:

```
[run]
data_file = tests/coverage/
omit = data-structures/*

[html]
directory = tests/coverage/html_report/

[xml]
output = tests/coverage/coverage.xml
```

Stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/bin/pytest", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_main())
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 187, in console_main
    code = main()
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 143, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 318, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 100, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()  # type: Config
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1003, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1280, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1186, in _preparse
    self.hook.pytest_load_initial_conftests(
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 126, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    plugin = CovPlugin(options, early_config.pluginmanager)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 177, in __init__
    self.start(engine.Central)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 199, in start
    self.cov_controller.start()
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/engine.py", line 44, in ensure_topdir_wrapper
    return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/engine.py", line 220, in start
    self.cov.erase()
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/control.py", line 582, in erase
    self._data.erase(parallel=self.config.parallel)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/sqldata.py", line 730, in erase
    file_be_gone(self._filename)
  File "/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/data-structures/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/misc.py", line 148, in file_be_gone
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/saurabh/Desktop/Data Structures/tests/coverage'
```

Am I doing this the wrong way or any suggestions on how I can fix this?

---

**Update**:

When I remove `data_file = tests/coverage/`, the coverage command is working fine. But should this be happening, because there is an option to change the data_file [here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.1/config.html#run) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to get it working by changing `.coveragerc` to:

```
[run]
omit = data-structures/*
data_file = tests/coverage/.coverage

[html]
directory = tests/coverage/html_report/

[xml]
output = tests/coverage/coverage.xml
```

Comment: you had initially set your coverage _file_ to be the same as a _directory_ that existed, coverage was trying to delete / replace that file and erroring

Comment: Yes. I posted a question earlier in which I set the path to the coverage *file*, instead of the *directory*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64703788/13055097